# Is it possible to find duplicating records in two columns simultaneously in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-13

I have the following database schema (oversimplified):

```sql
create sequence partners_partner_id_seq;


create table partners
(
    partner_id      integer      default nextval('partners_partner_id_seq'::regclass) not null primary key,
    name            varchar(255) default NULL::character varying,
    company_id      varchar(20)  default NULL::character varying,
    vat_id          varchar(50)  default NULL::character varying,
    is_deleted      boolean      default false not null
);

INSERT INTO partners(name, company_id, vat_id) VALUES('test1','1010109191191', 'BG1010109191192');
INSERT INTO partners(name, company_id, vat_id) VALUES('test2','1010109191191', 'BG1010109191192');
INSERT INTO partners(name, company_id, vat_id) VALUES('test3','3214567890102', 'BG1010109191192');
INSERT INTO partners(name, company_id, vat_id) VALUES('test4','9999999999999', 'GE9999999999999');
```

I am trying to figure out how to return `test1`, `test2` (because the `company_id` column value duplicates vertically) and `test3` (because the `vat_id` column value duplicates vertically as well).

To put it in other words - I need to find duplicating `company_id` and `vat_id` records and group them together, so that `test1`, `test2` and `test3` would be together, because they duplicate by `company_id` and `vat_id`.

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, LEAD(row, 1) OVER () AS nextrow
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (w) AS row
        FROM partners
        WHERE is_deleted = false
        AND ((company_id != '' AND company_id IS NOT null) OR (vat_id != '' AND vat_id IS NOT NULL))
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY company_id, vat_id ORDER BY partner_id DESC)
    ) x
) y
WHERE (row > 1 OR nextrow > 1) 
AND is_deleted = false
```

This successfully shows all `company_id` duplicates, but does not appear to show `vat_id` ones - `test3` row is missing. Is this possible to be done within one query?

Here is a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FBRKqMxAE6qaqP4w3Zrnv/1) with the schema, data and predefined query reproducing my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with recursion, but depending on the size of your data you may want to iterate, instead.

The trick is to make the `name` just another match key instead of treating it differently than the `company_id` and `vat_id`:

```
create table partners (
  partner_id integer generated always as identity primary key,
  name text,
  company_id text,
  vat_id text,
  is_deleted boolean not null default false
);

insert into partners (name, company_id, vat_id) values 
('test1','1010109191191', 'BG1010109191192'),
('test2','1010109191191', 'BG1010109191192'),
('test3','3214567890102', 'BG1010109191192'),
('test4','9999999999999', 'GE9999999999999'),
('test5','3214567890102', 'BG8888888888888'),
('test6','2983489023408', 'BG8888888888888')
;
```

I added a couple of test cases and left in the lone partner.

```
with recursive keys as (
  select partner_id, 
         array['n_'||name, 'c_'||company_id, 'v_'||vat_id] as matcher,
         array[partner_id] as matchlist,
         1 as size
    from partners
), matchers as (
  select *
    from keys
  union all
  select p.partner_id, c.matcher,
         p.matchlist||c.partner_id as matchlist,
         p.size + 1
    from matchers p
         join keys c
           on c.matcher && p.matcher
          and not p.matchlist @> array[c.partner_id]
), largest as (
  select distinct sort(matchlist) as matchlist
    from matchers m
   where not exists (select 1
                       from matchers
                      where matchlist @> m.matchlist
                        and size > m.size)
  -- and size > 1
)
select *
  from largest
;
```

| matchlist |
| --- |
| {1,2,3,5,6} |
| {4} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GRsCZLAf)

**EDIT UPDATE**

Since recursion did not perform, here is an iterative example in plpgsql that uses a temporary table:

```
create temporary table match1 (
  partner_id int not null,
  group_id int not null,
  matchkey uuid not null
);

create index on match1 (matchkey);
create index on match1 (group_id);

insert into match1 
select partner_id, partner_id, md5('n_'||name)::uuid from partners
union all
select partner_id, partner_id, md5('c_'||company_id)::uuid from partners
union all
select partner_id, partner_id, md5('v_'||vat_id)::uuid from partners;
```

```
do $$
  declare _cnt bigint;
  begin
    loop
      with consolidate as (
        select group_id, 
               min(group_id) over (partition by matchkey) as new_group_id
          from match1
      ), minimize as (
        select group_id, min(new_group_id) as new_group_id
          from consolidate
         group by group_id
      ), doupdate as (
        update match1
           set group_id = m.new_group_id
          from minimize m
         where m.group_id = match1.group_id
           and m.new_group_id != match1.group_id
        returning *
      )
      select count(*) into _cnt from doupdate;
      if _cnt = 0 then 
        exit;
      end if;
    end loop;
  end;
$$;
```

[updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DApK7Y2-)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! This query, however, does not execute on  a real PostgreSQL server: ```ERROR: function sort(integer[]) does not exist;  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 561```

Comment: @tftd Sorry.  Are you able to load the intarray extension?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/intarray.html

Comment: Yeah, after doing `CREATE EXTENSION intarray` it executes. Unfortunately, as you already pointed out, this query has very slow performance on about 100k data set. The query I initially posted returned the duplicates within less than a second and this has been running for more than 5 minutes now. This is supposed to show on a web page so offline processing would not be possible. Nevertheless I will upvote this to appreciate your effort!

Comment: @tftd If you cannot add the intarray extension, just add a CTE to sort:  https://dbfiddle.uk/yI_dBDwR

Comment: @tftd Here is an iteration example using a temporary table that should help with performance:  https://dbfiddle.uk/-ZLk4BAM